# Snap: Params type error

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I get this type error:

```
Couldn't match type `containers-0.5.0.0:Data.Map.Base.Map
                       ByteString [ByteString]'
              with `M.Map ByteString [ByteString]'
Expected type: M.Map ByteString [ByteString]
  Actual type: Params
```

But Params type is Map ByteString [ByteString]

```
type Params = Map ByteString [ByteString]
```

If it is of any help, this is the full function:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

categoryDoc :: Params -> Document
categoryDoc params = map (\(k,[v]) -> T.decodeUtf8 k =: T.decodeUtf8 v) $ M.toList params
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of containers installed? You can use `ghc-pkg list containers` to check.

Comment: @bennofs I do, indeed. I unregistered the other one and still get the same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have encountered **cabal hell**.

The problem is that there are multiple versions of the `containers` package installed. This means that there are two versions of the `Map` data type, one from `containers-0.5.0.0` and one from the other version. Those two won't match, and that's why you get the error.

---

The easiest solution to that problem is to delete the `~/.ghc` (on unix) directory and rebuilt everything. But that won't protect you from such problems in future, and there is also a chance that it won't work at all. So this is not a good solution.

If you have `cabal-install` of at least version 1.18, you can use the *cabal sandboxes* feature. This allows you to create an isolated package environment for each project, and thus avoid such conflicts. Just switch to your project and run:

```bsh
cabal sandbox init                        # Create a new sandbox
cabal install --only-dependencies         # Install dependencies
cabal build                               # Build your project
```

You can also use `cabal install` to install your project into the sandbox or `cabal repl` to start GHCi with the right settings for your project.

If you do not have a new-enough version of cabal-install and can't upgrade, you can use [cabal-dev](https://github.com/creswick/cabal-dev) to create and manage sandboxes.